# Are there any other brands like Xtrema?

Tags: food-safety, equipment

I'm looking for lead-free, cadmium-free, arsenic-free 100% ceramic cookware. Unfortunately, Xtrema is not available where I live. Are there any other brands like Xtrema?

Comment: Let's at least get the facts correct. Xtrema isn't certified to be "lead- free" but rather that it meets the US guidelines for "extractable" lead. Calcium is a typical component of ceramics, and any chemical that contains calcium will have some trace of lead. (I did XRF for years, and that is just a fact.) You can't buy milk for example that is absolutely lead free. The milk just has a very low level of lead.  So "lead-free" is a nice marketing point, but it is smoke and mirrors.

Comment: @MaxW The OP is worried about cadmium, not calcium

Comment: @ChrisH - The OP asked about several toxic heavy metals. Calcium and lead both form divalent cations, hence any compound that contains calcium will have at least some trace lead contamination. Also as I stated, calcium is a common component of ceramics, hence any ceramic containing calcium will have at least trace levels of lead.

Comment: Max: got a reference on that?  This is the first I've heard of a calcium-lead connection.

Comment: OP, you don't mention what region you live in.